# Flyway: Run script after migration

Tags: java, postgresql, flyway

Is it possible to run a flyway script after a real migration?
I mean, not after the call to `flyway.migrate()` rather after a migration gets successfully applied.

I already tried it with the "afterMigrate" `callback`, but unfortunately the `callback` runs on every app start. I want to run the `callback` only when the schema_version gets changed.

**DB:** PostgreSQL 9.5 x64

**Java:** 8u73 x86

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Beta

**UPDATE:**

Sry for my bad english... I try to better describe what i want to do:

*Migration Folder 1.0.0 - Database 1.0.0*

- Nothing should happen

*Migration Folder 1.0.1 - Database 1.0.0*

- Migration 1.0.1 runs
- My callback should run

*Migration Folder 1.0.2 - Database 1.0.0*

- Migration 1.0.1 runs
- Migration 1.0.2 runs
- My callback should run

Realy important is that in the first case the callback don't run.
If the callback would run in case two two times it wouldn't be a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

`afterEachMigrate` is the callback you want

Comment: What what this callback do in the first case described above?